# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Screen Not Working on new Dell G5 15

Tags: monitor

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. It was working very well with the nvidia drivers but suddenly (I don't know if maybe after an update) the dual monitor function stopped working. My computer is not able to recognize the other monitors. I tested with my second laptop and everything is working. I already checked the display configurations and everything is fine but the second monitor is not recognized.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: From the grub menu, if you select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** you can boot an older kernel. It might be worth checking to see if it was a recent kernel update that caused the dual monitor setup to stop working. The first entry is the current kernel (with a recovery mode underneath it) and any further entries are the 'older' kernels that you have previously been using - there should be at least one other entry to try.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Does it work normally in the guest session?

Comment: Oh wow. I just created the guest user, and now the dual monitor works (In the guest account). Why in my main account it doesn't work? :(

Comment: Hello! @AlbeiroE. Have you found a way to have a dual screen on your own session? And if so, how did you manage to do it?

Comment: I didn't manage to do it. I created a new session